# Display message if empty cells exist in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master(main) sheet that is compiled based on other worksheets. Once all other worksheets are copied onto the master, I need to run a code that will evaluate 1 column in particular and I need to display a text message saying "hey you have empty cells in said column". My problem is that the column always has different amount of rows so i cannot hard code the range. 
I also dont care for the number of empty cells but rather just 1 message saying you have empty cells is sufficient.

I tried below code with the intent on finding the active range within my column F and then if empty display the message but nothing.

```
Dim ABC22 As Long
With ActiveSheet
    ABC22 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    If IsEmpty("ABC22") = True Then
        MsgBox "Posting Key Column (F) contains empty cells"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this, here's one:

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Range("F1:F" & lastRow)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Posting Key Column (F) contains empty cells"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: even though i didnt have any empty cells, it still displayed the message. I suspect it might be because it's checking the entire column F rather than just the active rows within column F.

Answer (score 1):

Can be simplified with [`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) and two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> :

```
If [CountA(F:F)=0] Or Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
```

The `CountA(F:F)` checks if the column is completely empty, and the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> check if there is an empty cell before the last non-empty cell.

---

As a side note, `Cells` refers to the active sheet, so `With ActiveSheet` can be removed or replaced by specific sheet :

```
With Sheet("Sheet name")
    If .Evaluate("CountA(F:F)=0") Or .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
```

Comment: @BigBen thanks, you are right. I am not sure why I assumed there would always be some data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Count the special cells.

```
    Sub CountBlanks()
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    bCells = Range("F1:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
    MsgBox "There are " & bCells & " blank cells."
    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox "There are no blank cells"
    End Sub
```

Comment: This will work best if you have a column that won't contain any blank cells to establish the last row.

Comment: Didn't you mean to use column F to determine `lastRow`, not column A?

Comment: when it finds an empty cell it works properly. but if there are no empty cells, it gives an error.

Comment: @BigBen, I thought he could adjust the column reference himself, but I understand your comment so I changed the reference.  I don't think using the same column with blank cells is the best solution for establishing the last row because if the last row is the blank cell, it won't be counted with this examples. Todd Cee, you are correct, I added an error handler for times there are no blank cells.